# Action of $GL_n(k)$ on the space of polynomials in $n^2$ indeterminates

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, group-actions

I'm having a hard time with a proof where the author didn't specify the action. He just wrote:
"Note that $GL_n(k)$ acts on $k\big[X_{1,1},...,X_{n,n}\big]$ by substitution and leaves $k\big[X_{1,1},...,X_{n,n}\big]_{\leq N}$ invariant".

I really don't understand what the author meant there.

Comment: I guess it is meant that for $A\in GL_n$ and $P\in k[X_{11},\ldots,X_{nn}]$ the action is $(AP)(X_{11},\ldots,X_{nn}) = P((AX)_{11},\ldots,(AX)_{nn})$, where $X = (X_{11},\ldots,X_{nn})$.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll try to look at it again. (nice name btw)

Comment: BlueCharlie Thanks! :o)